# Modify a variable such as to get a particular correlation coefficient value with the other variable

Tags: regression, correlation, regression-coefficients, linear

I am working on a problem where i have to change a column to make it 0.75 correlated to some other column.

suppose i have two columns X1 and X2.

The current Pearson correlation coefficient between them is 0.10.

I want to modify X2 in some way such that the coefficient coefficient between X1 and X2_mod = 0.75

Is their a statistical way to go about doing it, i just cant figure out one without generating a whole new column from scratch.

PS. i have to do it for several columns, i.e. X1, X2... X100
and the goal is to have corr(X1,X2_mod) = 0.75, corr(X1,X3_mod) = 0.75, corr(X1,X4_mod) = 0.75 ..... corr(X1,X100_mod) = 0.75
We can assume using the Pearson Correaltion Coefficient and each column has about 10000 data points.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can change the correlation by adding a multiple of the variable you're taking the correlation with. That is, $X_{2^*}=X_2+kX_1$ for some $k$.
You can derive a quadratic equation in $k$ that is a function the new and old correlation and the variances of $X_2$ and $X_1$.

Comment: Oh i will try this and see if it works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the correlation by adding a multiple of the variable you're taking the correlation with. That is, $X_{2^*}=X_2+kX_1$ for some $k$.
You can derive a quadratic equation in $k$ that is a function the new and old correlation and the variances of $X_2$ and $X_1$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Cor}(X_2+kX_1,X_1) &=& \text{Cov}(X_2+kX_1,X_1)/\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_2+kX_1)\text{Var}(X_1)}\\
  &=& \frac{[\text{Cov}(X_2,X_1)+k\text{Cov}(X_1,X_1)]}{\sqrt{[\text{Var}(X_2)+2k\text{Cov}(X_2,X_1)+k^2\text{Var}(X_1)]\text{Var}(X_1)}}\\
  &=& \frac{\rho\sigma_2\sigma_1+k\sigma_1^2}{\sqrt{[\sigma_2^2+2k\rho\sigma_2\sigma_1+k^2\sigma_1^2]\sigma_1^2}}
\end{eqnarray}

That is,

$$\rho^2_\text{new} [\sigma_2^2+2k\rho\sigma_2\sigma_1+k^2\sigma_1^2]\sigma_1^2 = (\rho\sigma_2\sigma_1+k\sigma_1^2)^2$$

This is a quadratic equation in $k$, so we can rearrange to get coefficients of $k^2$, $k$ and the constant, plug into the usual quadratic formula and then remove the spurious root that was introduced by squaring, leaving the required $k$.

Comment: Wow this worked, i worked out the math from your previous comment and it worked for me, and this equation checks out with what i got. Thanks a lot. :D